# Monitor goes dead after some months

Tags: display

I have a VGA monitor,whenever I use the monitor after some weeks the screen starts to blur and after some time the monitor goes dead.This has happened a couple of times.I have changed many monitors from some past years.Is this a CPU fault or something like that?

Comment: Completely aggree with Mehper, if you can't be bothered to reward those that help you how can you expect people to be bothered to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the graphic card and/or the power supply (from the PC or the connection cable)